# Example for Digital Quantum Simulation of k-local Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-computer

I am currently going through Nielsen's Quantum Comp. and Quantum Information.

[image: Example: Digital Quantum Simulation]

I don't understand how this computes the time step for our three cubits. Why is there any action at all, the gate is just applied to the ancilla qubit. The variable Z means the Pauli-Z Matrix.

Comment: The CNOT gates produce entanglement between the ancilla and the data qubits, so what's done on the ancilla can affect the behavior of the data.

Comment: I see it now, having made my fingers dirty and using matrix rep. of the gates for the simple $H = Z$ Hamiltonian and comparing to the analytic solution.

Comment: You might try asking this at [SE.QuantumComputing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).